# Bypass override of operator new in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, visual-c++-2012

Is there a way to achieve a bypass of an override of `operator new`?

Something like this:

```
void* ::operator new( std::size_t size ) {
    void *p = ( ::operator new( size ) );  // But original, _not_ infinite recursion
    // do stuff with p
    return p; 
}
```

**Background:**
I have some legacy code, which we recently switched to compile with Visual Studio 2012. Now we get random crashes when `malloc` fails to `_heap_alloc` sufficient memory blocks. (Yes, the code is sprinkled with small memory leaks and other bad behaviour all over. But unfortunately a thorough cleanup is not realistic, it is somewhere around 500 000 SLOC.)

My current theory is that the cause is that almost all source files include a header with the following overrides of `operator new`:

```
void* ::operator new( std::size_t size ) {
    void* p = malloc( size );
    if( p == NULL )
        throw;
    // set memory to zero
    memset( p, 0, size );
    return p;
};

void* ::operator new[]( size_t count ) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
    // try to allocate count bytes for an array
    return (operator new(count));
}
```

There are no overrides of `delete`.

In essence, this means that the application mixes allocation using `malloc` with deallocation using `delete` instead of `free`.

First try to Q&D fix: 
Introduce overrides of `delete` that uses `free`. But this only partly helps, because sometimes include order and linked libraries still get it messed up.

Second try to Q&D fix: 
Remove the override. But the initialization of the memory to 0 is unfortunately necessary. A heritage from an old compiler used, which always did that, and coders that assumed C++ will always do that.

I am aware that new() will take care of that, but unfortunately i am not aware of any good method to make use of that without manually going through all the source code and updating it. It also won't help with poorly implemented classes which assumes all their members to be nullified without doing so in the constructor.

Therefore, my third idea of Q&D fix: 
Using the normal new in the override, as this question asks about.

Comment: use `=delete` on the operator new. 8.4.3 Deleted definitions of the standard  \may provide further details.

Comment: Your global `operator new` is most likely implemented in terms of `malloc` anyway (otherwise you would get a crash on the very first call to `delete`). So the only thing this override does differently is zero-filling the memory. Doing what you want is unlikely to help (even if it were possible), as the current version already does exactly the same thing. Adding overrides for `delete` is unlikely to help, as the current version already does exactly the same thing (though I would do it anyway for consistency). *You need to fix real memory bugs.* No way around this.

Comment: @n.m., Thank you for the comment. I have checked the source files included with Visual Studio, and it appears to me that `operator new` isn't implemented with `malloc` in MS C++. Both `malloc` and `operator new` are implemented with `_heap_alloc`, but with differences in what i understand to be some book-keeping.

Comment: So you need to move the overrides out of the header and into a proper source file, and add the overrides for `delete`. There is no reason in the world why this would mess up anything; if it does, you need to sort out this issue because who knows where else it will harm your project.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to achieve a bypass of an override of operator new?

None that I'm aware of, but why don't you simply re-implement it in your custom function in the same manner MS did it in their _heap_alloc-based implementation and just add your customization to it?

One do-or-die allocation attempt only is anyway not what MS does:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/we2zys4d.aspx

> The default behavior is to execute a loop. Within the loop, the
>   function first attempts to allocate the requested storage

Anyway- I second what n.m. put in a comment

> You need to fix real memory bugs

That is self-explaning; for those any debugging purposes - pls have a look at std::set_new_handler.

Btw - there some things that I find irritating about your code

- the explicit qualifications of the operator
- not throwing std::bad_alloc but re-throwing outside of a catch-block

Happy Hacking!

Regards, S.

P.S.:@all: I cannot  "vote up" that question due my limited exp here, but I recommend doing that. It's a very interesting topic and a well formulated.